# Как сделать адаптивный инвентарь в unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

При использовании различных гайдов и подобных статей, люди юзают групированную сетку(грид лояут груп), но у этого компонента есть минус, размер клеток и отступы между ними прописываются в самом компоненте, а при изменении разрешения эти значения могут оказаться большими(инвентарь уйдёт за рамки панели), либо наоборот, при изменении на более крупное разрешение, инвентарь может оказаться маленьким и занимать треть панели, вопрос такой, как написать инвентарь, который будет являться масштабируемым(адаптивным) под разные разрешения
P. S. Код на библеотеку предметов писать умеем, интересует, как сделать адаптивность.

Просьба не писать ответы и комментарии по типу: "там все настраивается, смотри внимательнее" или "есть куча ассэтов, возьми готовый".

Comment: Есть предположение использовать canvas scaler и поставить сетке настройку flexible, но проверить прямо сейчас не могу

Comment: @trollingchar , попробывал canvas scaler, он вешается на канвас, если создать канвас внутири, разницы нет, ибо в grid layout group прописываются значения ширины и высоты ячейки и при скейле они не изменяются, а остаются фиксированными, fiexible  стоит, прост автоматически переносит клетки

Comment: Тогда можете написать более конкретно (а лучше нарисовать) как интерфейс на разных разрешениях должен выглядеть? А то мне так сложно понять.

Comment: @trollingchar , любая UI панель с grid layout group(не навесь экран), попробуй, создай, поставь платформу андройд и посмотри на разных расширениях на сетку, разрешение в landscape ориентации

Comment: Тогда чем вам не нравится отдельный канвас со скейлером настроенным на Expand? У меня в игре так сделано и все норм на любом разрешении